# Install Cypress via "npm" works but not login via GUI

Tags: cypress

At my company we had some proxy settings which restricted the installation of cypress via CMD->npm.
After some discussions with the network guys we added *.cypress.io and registry.npmjs.org to the proxy settings and after that "npm install cypress" worked perfectly. The message "Finished Installation" is shown and I could also open the Cypress GUI by typing "node_modules.bin\cypress open" in CMD.

But when the GUI was opened I tried to click on the LogIn button I get "Cannot connect to API server"

"We tried but failed to connect to the API server at https://api.cypress.io/"

Any idea why I cannot connect to the api server when I just did the whole installation without any problems?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're getting this error - my best guess is that the request for `api.cypress.io` is also hitting another server that isn't allowed through your firewall. Most likely this is Github, as the only option for logging in is by connecting your Github account.

That said, unless you're using the [dashboard service](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/dashboard-service.html#Overview), **you don't actually need to log in to run tests**. If the `Log In` button works properly, you'll get a message that looks like this:

> Logging in gives you access to the [Cypress Dashboard Service](https://dashboard.cypress.io/#/login). You can set up projects to be recorded and see test data from your project.

This message is accompanied by a button prompting you to log in via Github.

Comment: I checked with the network guy and he is able to see that when I use GUI I actually don´t go via the proxy where he has enabled cypress.io to work. Where is the cypress.config file located and is it possible in that file to set the same proxy I set when I installed the Cypress via "npm" from CMD?

Comment: Do you need the Cypress dashboard service? If not, you shouldn't need to log in.